# Self-written R package does not find its own function

Tags: r, r-package

I created a package with some functions which are helpful at my company. Recently, I restructered the package such that there are helper functions which need not to be accessible for everyone, but are called internally from other (exported) functions of the package. These helper functions are not exported to the namespace (no `#' @export` in the respective `.R` files).

Now, when I call one of the "major" (exported) functions, I get the error message (no real function names):

> Error in major_function() : could not find function "helper_function"

Im fairly new in building packages, but from what I understood so far (from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html), it should neither be necessary to export the helper functions, nor to add `#' importFrom my_package helper_function` to the `.R` file of the major function.

When I tried this, it actually produced errors when checking the package. I also tried to call the helper functions with `my_package:::helper_function`, but this lead to the note that it should almost never be necessary to call functions from the same package like this.

**Maybe useful information:**

The error occurs only when I call a `major_function_1` which internally calls `major_function_2` which calls a `helper_function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is more to your problem than what you state. As long as all your functions are defined in the same namespace (this also means that all your functions need to live in .R files in the same folder), the calling function should find the helper-functions accordingly.
I suspect you have your helper functions nested in some way, and that is causing the problem.

I recommend to recheck your namespace structure, or post a simplistic outline of your package here.

Another reason that could come to mind, is that you do not export your 'mayor_function2' in your `NAMESPACE`-file in your package root (maybe you have not recompiled the Roxygen documentation generating this file), and additionally have a local shadow of the the calling function 'mayor_function1'. Try to check this and rerun from a clean compile.

Comment: What is the problem with nested helper functions? And how can I avoid related problems?

Comment: there is no problem as long as you track their namespaces correctly. This means, if they are local to your package, make sure that they live in the same namespace as your exported functions, if they are not living in the same namespace, e.g. a different package, you need to import that package and see to it that this package exports them (if you can influence that). [Also don't forget to recompile Roxygen, the package and work from a clean environment everytime :) ]

Comment: I checked the structure again, did not change anything, recompiled the package et voilà, it worked. I have no clue what was wrong before. I guess, I somehoew messed up with changing different things without a clean recompile (even though I thought I did this).

Comment: I had the same isssue, my custom made package was not able to call the function defined inside it and I build and installed that package through LInux and not from R Studio. Found out that NAMESPACE was not having that function name, added it and it worked fine.

Comment: @SomDubey:  That means you exported the function.  That's a different issue than this old question, where the author claims a function which is not exported is not visible to other functions in the same package.